# Создание флешки восстановления

Tags: ос

Подскажите, плиз, какой ещё (бесплатной) программой, кроме ultraiso, можно  для этого пользоваться?

Comment: Восстановления чего, чем, как? Вопрос слишком неконкретный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще вопрос поставлен немного странно, и непонятно что именно вы собираетесь восстанавливать. Могу допустить что речь идет о восстановлении Windows. Для создания такой флешки подойдет так же:

1. [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) - подойдет для создания загрузочных флешек, для записи всяких программ.
2. WinToFlash - подойдет для записи windows на флешку.
3. Так же возможность записи есть у стандартной утилиты от майкрософта насколько я помню.

Лично я отдаю предпочтение Rufus так как эта программа довольно легка в освоении и имеет большой функционал, но это выбор программы зависит только от вас.

### UPDATE

Для записи текущего состояния системы вам нужно воспользоваться программой AcronisTrueImage. В чем суть программы - вы заходите через дос в программу которая сидит на флешке, и выбираете нужный вам диск для создания образа системы. Дальше программа быстро или не очень создает образ вашего диска и системы соответственно если это диск С. Дальше вы к примеру убили систему, и вам нужно откатится к какому-то состоянию. Вы опять заходите на эту флешку, выбираете восстановление и выбираете образ системы который вам нужен. Лично я создавал несколько образов - совсем чистая (после установки сразу), с драйверами, и с программами. [Вот](http://webwulpix.ru/problemi-zagruzki/24-kak-sozdat-zagruzochnyu-fleshku-s-acronis-true-image.html) есть ссылка с инструкцией. Так же насколько я помню у винды есть такая возможность создания точек восстановления для отката системы к какому-то состоянию.

### UPDATE_2.0

Как уже отметил [@Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt) флешка нужна только для Acronis а сам образ может хранится на другом носителе, на том же диске который вы снимаете для образа. Дальше просто при восстановления не забудьте подключить этот носитель.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101467/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-mathem).

Comment: Тут вот новый поворот. Купили флешку на 32 гб. Начал пробовать средствами системы : я пока не хочу ничего ставить , хочу сделать образ как он был после, так сказать, знающего чела. Ну, и вот. Начал я пробовать сделать образ на эту флешку. Однако при выборе  её в качестве места для архива, кнопка Далее была упорно недоступна в продолжении нескольких попыток. Тогда я плюнул на всё и попробовал  указать в качестве места для архива несистемный жёсткой диска ноута. Кнопка Далее стала доступна . На следующем шаге он написал мне, что под архив потребуется примерно  37 гб.

Comment: Видимо, поэтому тогда флешка была недоступна при выборе ее для записи на неё образа. Короче, получилось у меня создать этот образ, его размер получился, вопреки обещаниям, 27, 9 гб. И зачем  было делать так, что кнопка Далее заранее недоступна ? Ладно . А теперь я хочу просто скопировать тот образ на флешку. Какдумаете, изготовленный так образ будет  полностью неотличим от того образа, который я бы получил если бы у меня  была флешка достаточного размера и при создани образа стандартным способом я бы для архива выбрал эту флешку?

Comment: сейчас модераторы будут ругаться, там выше есть ссылка для чата, по поводу неотличимости образа я ничего с уверенностью сказать не могу, нужно смотреть что получите после развертки, я работал с сторонним по поэтому в вопросах связанных с по от виндовс не очень искушен :)